# With JavaScript/jQuery How would I sort/resort this JSON object on the fly to support various displays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

Running over this string.. and Resorting it as needed on the fly

```
{
"oozie": {
    "admin": {},
    "hosts-list": [
        "1"
    ],
    "hostsinfo": [
        {
            "host-id": "1",
            "details": "Failed ProcessHealthMonitor health check 1 times consecutively",
            "currstatus": "Warning",
            "currstatusclass": "warning"
        },
        {
            "host-id": "2",
            "details": "Failed ProcessHealthMonitor health check 1 times consecutively",
            "currstatus": "Warning",
            "currstatusclass": "warning"
        },
        {
            "host-id": "4",
            "details": "Failed ProcessHealthMonitor health check 1 times consecutively",
            "currstatus": "Warning",
            "currstatusclass": "warning"
        },
        {
            "host-id": "5",
            "details": "Failed ProcessHealthMonitor health check 1 times consecutively",
            "currstatus": "Warning",
            "currstatusclass": "warning"
        }
    ],
    "status": [
        {}
    ]
},
"single-namenode": {
    "admin": {},
    "hosts-list": [
        "1"
    ],
    "hostsinfo": [
        {
            "host-id": "1",
            "details": "Running Service",
            "currstatus": "Running",
            "currstatusclass": "success"
        }
    ],
    "status": [
        {}
    ]
},
"single-database": {
    "admin": {},
    "hosts-list": [
        "1"
    ],
    "hostsinfo": [
        {
            "host-id": "1",
            "details": "Running Service",
            "currstatus": "Running",
            "currstatusclass": "success"
        }
    ],
    "status": [
        {}
    ]
},
"secondarynamenode": {
    "admin": {},
    "hosts-list": [
        "1"
    ],
    "hostsinfo": [
        {
            "host-id": "1",
            "details": "Running Service",
            "currstatus": "Running",
            "currstatusclass": "success"
        }
    ],
    "status": [
        {}
    ]
},
"datanode": {
    "admin": {},
    "hosts-list": [
        "1"
    ],
    "hostsinfo": [
        {
            "host-id": "1",
            "details": "Failed HttpHealthMonitor health check 2 times consecutively",
            "currstatus": "Warning",
            "currstatusclass": "warning"
        }
    ],
    "status": [
        {}
    ]
},
"web": {
    "admin": {},
    "hosts-list": [
        "1"
    ],
    "hostsinfo": [
        {
            "host-id": "1",
            "details": "Setting Master IP",
            "currstatus": "Dead",
            "currstatusclass": "error"
        }
    ],
    "status": [
        {}
    ]
},
"tasktracker": {
    "admin": {},
    "hosts-list": [
        "1"
    ],
    "hostsinfo": [
        {
            "host-id": "1",
            "details": "Running Service",
            "currstatus": "Running",
            "currstatusclass": "success"
        }
    ],
    "status": [
        {}
    ]
},
"jobtracker": {
    "admin": {},
    "hosts-list": [
        "1"
    ],
    "hostsinfo": [
        {
            "host-id": "1",
            "details": "Running Master Service",
            "currstatus": "Running",
            "currstatusclass": "success"
        }
    ],
    "status": [
        {}
    ]
}
}
```

I have a string similar to that of the above, that changes rather frequently. Using Jquery I want to be able to sort this string on the fly in different mannors. One example Is I want to list all services specific to one host. Or Another is I want to List all services by service type.

Currently this string supports the by service type concept. However I am not really able to get the output to change to my whims so I have to work with what I got. That said whats the best way to sort this string or object I should actually be saying. So that I can show a block that would be all services in one particular host?

I've been trying to do it myself for a couple days and I haven't gotten anywhere I just figure I need a fresh set of eyes on this to give me ideas cause the directions I run seem to road block me..

I have been trying `each()` in jquery where I nest a few each's down in some trials to do what I want but again I am failing miserably.

***EDIT***
I figured its better to just rebuild the object based on the information I need from the original. I am however getting stuck in gathering that information. Basicly I want the hostsinfo and the main object name of hosts info.

so I would want to return:

oozie = hostid:1, details:.., currstatus:.., currstatusclass:..
oozie = hostid:2, details:.., currstatus:.., currstatusclass:..
oozie = hostid:3, details:.., currstatus:.., currstatusclass:..
(just imagine the above 3 lines in object format)

My Latest Failed attempt. Ive been at this for days and im starting to lose my mind.

```
$('.refreshAllb').click(function() {
    var outputCon = '';
    $.getJSON('services.json', function(data) {
        $('#master_service_container').empty();
        $.each(data, function(i, object){
            $.each(object, function(property, value){
                if(property == "hostsinfo")
                {
                    $.each(value, function(propertyX, valueX){
                        outputCon += propertyX[valueX] +'<br>';
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        $('#master_service_container').html(outputCon);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your JSON structure, and assuming you have control over it I would change it slightly to make it an array of hosts, with the node name as a property. If you can't change it I would parse it first to make an array that you can work with.

I would then use the LINQ.js jQuery plugin to sort and select as needed.

Check out the linq.js site here:

http://linqjs.codeplex.com/

And the LINQ.js linqpad and API reference here:

http://neue.cc/reference.htm

I'm not quite clear on how you want to sort this JSON. But as an example, lets assume your nodes are in a variable called "nodes" and we want to select the running hosts:

```
var running = $.Enumerable.From(nodes).Where("$.hostsinfo.currstatus == 'Running'").ToArray()
```

There are many more query operators that you can use, this is a simple example. Sub queries are also supported.

Comment: unfortunately the JSON is the way it is, I have no control over that object. Essentially right now its spit out where each service type will be spit out with its matching hosts. So lets say oozie has 3 hosts it will spit out ozzie as the service, host1, host2, host3, host4 with it. That by itself is alright for one pattern of display we want however the other type of display is each host showing its services say host one had a singlenamenode and ozzie and one other. We would like to display a list like that as well based off the existing object.